# install RApache module in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

I'm using Ubuntu 13, it is installed PHP5, Apache2 and MySQL.
I want to use R with the PHP script.
I'm following a tutorial 
http://blog.valugi.ro/2011/03/30/rapache-install-in-ubuntu-10-04-lts
but when I run step 6:

```
 a2nmod r
```

I get the error:

```
No command 'a2nmod' found, did you mean:
Command 'a2enmod' from package 'apache2.2-common' (main)
a2nmod: command not found
```

I do not know if I'm installing the module correctly.
There is another tutorial on how to install the Apache RApache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a2enmod` = Apache2 Enable Mod. Looks like a typo on the tutorial you are following.